# Copy and Paste Worksheet to Another Workbook then return to the Workbook you Copied From

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CopyPasteDataInMaster()
    Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = Sheets("Consolidated").UsedRange
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1)
        Rng.Copy
        Workbooks.Open "S:\AAA.xlsx"
        Workbooks("AAA.xlsx").Sheets("NewData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("AAA.xlsx").Worksheets("NewData").Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub

Sub CopyPastePersonDataInMaster()
    Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = Sheets("ByPerson").UsedRange
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1)
        Rng.Copy
        Workbooks.Open "S:\AAA.xlsx"
        Workbooks("AAA.xlsx").Sheets("NewDataPerson").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("AAA.xlsx").Worksheets("NewDataPerson").Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

I'd like to call these two back to back, but an issue arises when it's still on the "AAA" file from the first paste and cannot grab the "ByPerson" sheet for second paste.

I have to run this for multiple different files (multiple copy locations, same destination) and I need for it to be universal for whichever sheet I'm copying from.

Maybe a way to "reactivate" the sheet I copied from at the end of the first macro so when it runs the second macro it can find the sheet name.

Thanks for your help.

New Code---How does it look? It works perfect now. Thanks for the advice!

```
Sub NewCopyPasteMaster()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open "S:\AAA.xlsx"
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Activate
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Consolidated")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("ByPerson")
    Set Rng = ws1.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    Set Rng2 = ws2.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    Rng.Copy
    wb2.Sheets("NewData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wb2.Worksheets("NewData").Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb.Activate
    Rng2.Copy
    wb2.Sheets("NewDataPerson").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wb2.Worksheets("NewDataPerson").Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Open` method returns a workbook object you can use. Why aren't you using it that way?

Comment: Use more `Range` variables too, there's too many manually-entered workbook/sheet names; it'd be easier to edit if you add some variables.  You can call the second function as a new line in the first, `Call CopyPastePersonDataInMaster` I believe. Also you can pass variables (e.g. worksheet names, ranges). Edit: Per your new comment, I really recommend looking up how to set Worksheet/Workbook variables, e.g. `Dim wb as Workbook // Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`.  That way you don't even need to know the name...

Comment: The Workbook I am copying from will change, so I would have to update the file name every time. The code before this adds two new sheets to a file with specific data and then I need to copy the data on each Sheet and Paste into two different Sheets in the Master. "Consolidated" and "ByPerson" will be universal in all the Workbooks I will be copying from.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' advice. I re-posted my new code that works. Any other advice is appreciated as I'm very new to this. Cheers